# pip install kivy gives me an huuge error (Windows)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, kivy

I want to start working with pip in pycharm and I'm having problems installing kivy.

So what I tried to install was:

kivy 1.11.1
I have installed:
python 3.8 on windows
but in pycharm in the project interpreter it show python 3.7 to me (whyever)

I tried installing kivy by doing:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools
python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew
python -m pip install kivy.deps.gstreamer
python -m pip install kivy.deps.angle
```

(worked until here)

```
python -m pip install kivy
```

this line gives me this output in windows command prompt:

```
python -m pip install kivy
Collecting kivy
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1b/4d/3f8a720f561dc1eabe036c0d87c6ce9d02823275391265538e606f45e37a/Kivy-1.11.1.tar.gz
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Gamer\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-iah9bpw6\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Gamer\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-iah9bpw6\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-iah9bpw6\kivy\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-iah9bpw6\kivy\
    Complete output (192 lines):
    Using setuptools
    User distribution detected, avoid portable command.
    Using this graphics system: OpenGL
    WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0 (code 1)

    b'Der Befehl "pkg-config" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder\r\nkonnte nicht gefunden werden.\r\n'

    WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0 (code 1)

    b'Der Befehl "pkg-config" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder\r\nkonnte nicht gefunden werden.\r\n'

    WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags sdl2 SDL2_ttf SDL2_image SDL2_mixer (code 1)

    b'Der Befehl "pkg-config" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder\r\nkonnte nicht gefunden werden.\r\n'

    ERROR: Dependency for context.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for compiler.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for context_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for fbo.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for gl_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for opengl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for opengl_utils.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for shader.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for stencil_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for scissor_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for texture.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for vbo.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for vertex.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for vertex_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl_mock.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl_gl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl_glew.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl_sdl2.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for svg.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    Compiling C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-5f60h8re\Cython-0.29.10\Cython\Plex\Scanners.py because it changed.
    Compiling C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-5f60h8re\Cython-0.29.10\Cython\Plex\Actions.py because it changed.
    Compiling C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-5f60h8re\Cython-0.29.10\Cython\Compiler\Scanning.py because it changed.
    Compiling C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-5f60h8re\Cython-0.29.10\Cython\Compiler\Visitor.py because it changed.
    Compiling C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-5f60h8re\Cython-0.29.10\Cython\Compiler\FlowControl.py because it changed.
    Compiling C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-5f60h8re\Cython-0.29.10\Cython\Runtime\refnanny.pyx because it changed.
    Compiling C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-5f60h8re\Cython-0.29.10\Cython\Compiler\FusedNode.py because it changed.
    Compiling C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-5f60h8re\Cython-0.29.10\Cython\Tempita\_tempita.py because it changed.
    [1/8] Cythonizing C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-5f60h8re\Cython-0.29.10\Cython\Compiler\FlowControl.py
    [2/8] Cythonizing C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-5f60h8re\Cython-0.29.10\Cython\Compiler\FusedNode.py
    [3/8] Cythonizing C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-5f60h8re\Cython-0.29.10\Cython\Compiler\Scanning.py
    [4/8] Cythonizing C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-5f60h8re\Cython-0.29.10\Cython\Compiler\Visitor.py
    [5/8] Cythonizing C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-5f60h8re\Cython-0.29.10\Cython\Plex\Actions.py
    [6/8] Cythonizing C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-5f60h8re\Cython-0.29.10\Cython\Plex\Scanners.py
    [7/8] Cythonizing C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-5f60h8re\Cython-0.29.10\Cython\Runtime\refnanny.pyx
    [8/8] Cythonizing C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-5f60h8re\Cython-0.29.10\Cython\Tempita\_tempita.py
     Unable to find pgen, not compiling formal grammar.
     warning: no files found matching 'Doc\*'
     warning: no files found matching '*.pyx' under directory 'Cython\Debugger\Tests'
     warning: no files found matching '*.pxd' under directory 'Cython\Debugger\Tests'
     warning: no files found matching '*.pxd' under directory 'Cython\Utility'
     warning: no files found matching 'pyximport\README'
     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
         dist.run_commands()
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
         self.run_command(cmd)
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
         cmd_obj.run()
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 172, in run
         cmd = self.call_command('install_lib', warn_dir=0)
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 158, in call_command
         self.run_command(cmdname)
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
         self.distribution.run_command(command)
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
         cmd_obj.run()
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install_lib.py", line 11, in run
         self.build()
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\command\install_lib.py", line 107, in build
         self.run_command('build_ext')
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
         self.distribution.run_command(command)
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
         cmd_obj.run()
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 84, in run
         _build_ext.run(self)
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 340, in run
         self.build_extensions()
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 449, in build_extensions
         self._build_extensions_serial()
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 474, in _build_extensions_serial
         self.build_extension(ext)
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 205, in build_extension
         _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 528, in build_extension
         objects = self.compiler.compile(sources,
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 360, in compile
         self.initialize()
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 253, in initialize
         vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 171, in msvc14_get_vc_env
         return EnvironmentInfo(plat_spec, vc_min_ver=14.0).return_env()
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 1075, in __init__
         self.si = SystemInfo(self.ri, vc_ver)
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 547, in __init__
         vc_ver or self._find_latest_available_vs_ver())
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 561, in _find_latest_available_vs_ver
         raise distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError(
     distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

     During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
         yield saved
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
         yield
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
         _execfile(setup_script, ns)
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 45, in _execfile
         exec(code, globals, locals)
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-5f60h8re\Cython-0.29.10\setup.py", line 228, in <module>
         This version of Cython is untested with Kivy. While this version may
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
         return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 163, in setup
         raise SystemExit("error: " + str(msg))
     SystemExit: error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

     During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1144, in run_setup
         run_setup(setup_script, args)
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 253, in run_setup
         raise
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
         self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
         yield
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
         self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 166, in save_modules
         saved_exc.resume()
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 141, in resume
         six.reraise(type, exc, self._tb)
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\six.py", line 685, in reraise
         raise value.with_traceback(tb)
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
         yield saved
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
         yield
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
         _execfile(setup_script, ns)
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 45, in _execfile
         exec(code, globals, locals)
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-5f60h8re\Cython-0.29.10\setup.py", line 228, in <module>
         This version of Cython is untested with Kivy. While this version may
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
         return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 163, in setup
         raise SystemExit("error: " + str(msg))
     SystemExit: error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

     During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-iah9bpw6\kivy\setup.py", line 1073, in <module>
         setup(
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 144, in setup
         _install_setup_requires(attrs)
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 139, in _install_setup_requires
         dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 717, in fetch_build_eggs
         resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 780, in resolve
         dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1065, in best_match
         return self.obtain(req, installer)
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1077, in obtain
         return installer(requirement)
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 787, in fetch_build_egg
         return cmd.easy_install(req)
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 679, in easy_install
         return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 705, in install_item
         dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 890, in install_eggs
         return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1158, in build_and_install
         self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
       File "C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1146, in run_setup
         raise DistutilsError("Setup script exited with %s" % (v.args[0],))
     distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Kivy didn't publish [wheels for Python 3.8 yet](https://pypi.org/project/Kivy/1.11.1/#files). So either you downgrade to Python 3.7 or compile from source. For the latter you need compiler: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+Microsoft+Visual+C%2B%2B+14.0+is+required

Comment: thank you sir. i downgraded to 3.7 now and it works now

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, also used python 3.8. Win, and installed it via Git:

- pip install git+https://github.com/kivy/kivy

It worked for me. Notice, that you need the C++ Compiler to work too:

- https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=16
- C++ Buildtools